# Is it possible to force Compile-Only with CMake?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cmake

I've got a very huge project (~180 libs, ~1Mio LOC, CMake but exclusively developed with VS2017 + permissive, ~30 third-parties) that needs to get ported to Linux

i know that there will be many C++ Syntax and Linker-Dependency Problems - missing typenames, includes, Platform differences etc. - i've done such porting several times but not on this scale

is it possible to force some sort of Compile-Only so i can firstly focus on syntax problems and then going over to the linker problems?

i found serveral Tricks&Tips but they do not work very good on that project scale - i don't want to change every CMakeLists.txt if possible

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could modify the project so that you create libraries rather than executables?

Comment: I don't think CMake has any such capabilities. Your best bet is either what @Lindydancer said or some specific flags of the target compilers. For example, clang [has flags](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#stage-selection-options) by setting which you have control over what it is going to do including not running the linker.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good approach. Identifying parts of the project and fixing those completely first could yield intermediate results that could be of use even without the whole migration being completed. Fixing a part of the problem for each target, but not all of it may leave you with no intermediate results until you're done with a major part of the work...

Comment: You might want to use something like `ninja -k 0` to continue building after errors.

Comment: thanks for all the tips i will first only do add_library so no linking will happen - that will keep me mostly away from problems with 3rd-parties - at first - and i can check in paralell that the code still builds with VS2017 - after that step most of the tiny microsoft VS2017/gcc C++ differences will be fixed/more standard then - next step will be building the 3rd-parties and start to link